# How do i shorten time this GAS code(search correct column and data paste)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, optimization

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VAJk.png

i want to copy data from "dB" sheet A5:A29 and paste to correct column.
so i use the script to find the correct column.

there range B2:CX2 have 0(not-correct) or 1(correct) value, so i use 'for' & 'if'
BUT!! It's too delay!!
i use console.time() and i get 25909ms(timecheck2 value) !!!

please help me.....

here is my code

```
function save(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('dB');
  
  console.time("timecheck1");
  //find last row
  var copyrangeO = sheet.getRange(5,1,25,1).getValues();
  var lastrowO = copyrangeO.filter(String).length; 
  var copyrange = sheet.getRange(5,1,lastrowO,1);
  console.timeEnd("timecheck1");
  
  //my dB data start "B2". 
  var cv = 1;
  
  //find correct value(1). B2 ~ CX2 (#100)
  console.time("timecheck2");
  for (var i=2; i<101;i++){
    if(sheet.getRange(2,i).getValue()===1){
      cv = i;
    }
  }
  console.timeEnd("timecheck2");

  //if data isn't correct, cv===1. so error msg print.
  console.time("timecheck3");
  if(cv ===1){
    Browser.msgBox("ERROR")
  }else {
    //data copy and paste.
    var columnToCheck = sheet.getRange(4,cv,1000).getValues();
    var lastrow = getLastRowSpecial(columnToCheck);
    var pasterange = sheet.getRange(lastrow+4,cv);
    copyrange.copyTo(pasterange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
    Browser.msgBox(lastrowO + " saved!");
  }
  console.timeEnd("timecheck3");
  
}
```

Comment: It's really pretty difficult to tell what you're trying to accomplish so perhaps it might be easier just to suggest taking a look at best practices in the documentation.  Try to avoid using getValue() and instead use getValues() and then iterate through the array of values.

Comment: Have you looked at "Best practices"? See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for free resources and more details.

Comment: You do not need `copyrangeO.filter(String).length` since you already manually set the range above, i.e. row 5, and 25 rows down. So you can skip this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

If I understand your situation correctly, you want to find the cell in `B2:CX2` in which the value is `1`, but the script is taking too much time for this.

The problem here is that you are using [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)) and [getValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) in a loop (`sheet.getRange(2,i).getValue()===1`). This greatly increases the amount of calls to the Sheets service, which slows down your script, as you can see at [Minimize calls to other services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#minimize_calls_to_other_services).

#### Solution:

In that case, I'd suggest doing the following:

- Get the values from all columns at once using [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues).
- Use [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get the column index for which value is `1`.

In order to do that, replace this:

```
var cv = 1;

//find correct value(1). B2 ~ CX2 (#100)
console.time("timecheck2");
for (var i=2; i<101;i++){
  if(sheet.getRange(2,i).getValue()===1){
    cv = i;
  }
}
```

With this:

```
var ROW_INDEX = 2;
var FIRST_COLUMN = 2; // Column B
var LAST_COLUMN = 102; // Column CX
var columnValues = sheet.getRange(ROW_INDEX, FIRST_COLUMN, 1, LAST_COLUMN-FIRST_COLUMN+1).getValues()[0];
var cv = columnValues.findIndex(columnValue => columnValue === 1) + FIRST_COLUMN;
```

#### Note:

If there's no cell in the range with value `1`, `findIndex` returns `-1` which, added to `FIRST_COLUMN`, results in `1`. That's appropriate for your current script, but won't work if the `FIRST_COLUMN` stops being `2`, so be careful with this (either change the condition `if(cv ===1){` to something less strict, or don't assign the resulting value to `cv` if `findIndex` returns `-1`).

Answer (score 0):

The function will spend most of its time in the `for` loop because it repeats the `Range.getValue()` call many times. You can speed things up quite a bit by getting all values with *one* `Range.getValues()` call, like this:

```
  let cv = 1;
  console.time("timecheck2");
  sheet.getRange('B2:B100').getValues().flat()
    .some((value, index) => (cv = 2 + index) && value === 1);
  console.timeEnd("timecheck2");
```

Note that this is not a cleanest way of finding `cv`, but it should help illustrate why you have a performance issue. You may want to do a complete rewrite of the code, using declarative instead of imperative style.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I don't know what you're doing in the save because to did not supply the helper function code.

```
function save(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('dB');
  var vs0 = sh.getRange(5,1,25,1).getValues();
  var lr0 = vs0.filter(String).length; 
  var crg = sh.getRange(5,1,lr0,1);
  var cv = 1;
  const vs1 = sh.getRange(2,2,1,99).getValues().forEach((c,i) => {
    if(c == 1)cv = i + 2
  })
  if(cv == 1){
    Browser.msgBox("ERROR")
  }else {
    var vs2 = sh.getRange(4,cv,1000).getValues();
    var lastrow = getLastRowSpecial(vs2);
    var drg = sh.getRange(lastrow+4,cv);
    crg.copyTo(drg, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
    Browser.msgBox(lr0 + " saved!");
  }
}
```